# Pom.xml Error Inside Apache Nutch Source Code / Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, nutch

I downloaded Apache Nutch project and everything seems to be fine, except for this one annoying pom.xml error that never seems to go away. I have eclipse kepler and converted the apache nutch project to a maven project and then updated the dependencies. However this error does not seem to go away at all. All inputs/feedbacks are welcome & highly appreciated.

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
        - Missing artifact javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1
        - ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:jar:1.2.1 from https://maven-
         repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until 
         the update interval of java.net has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact 
         com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:jar:1.2.1 from/to java.net (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository): No 
         connector available to access repository java.net (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository) of type 
         legacy using the available factories AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
        - ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1 from https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/
         nonav/repository was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of 
         java.net has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1 from/to 
         java.net (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository): No connector available to access repository 
         java.net (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository) of type legacy using the available factories 
         AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
        - ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer com.sun.jmx:jmxri:jar:1.2.1 from https://maven-
         repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until 
         the update interval of java.net has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact 
         com.sun.jmx:jmxri:jar:1.2.1 from/to java.net (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository): No 
         connector available to access repository java.net (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository) of type 
         legacy using the available factories AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
        - Missing artifact com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:jar:1.2.1
        - Missing artifact com.sun.jmx:jmxri:jar:1.2.1
```

Comment: To add to my question I have tried everywhere to download javax.jms. Not only is it very hard to find, the one version I downloaded and manually added to my build path failed to resolve this issue. The POM still complains of this dependency. Although it is not preventing the build process itself, I still don't like to see errors in pom.xml. I like to see the project in a perfectly buildable state...

Answer (score 0):

there is a artifact online in http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jms/jms/1.1 from (Oct 07, 2013). It should work than.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```